# EF Migrations - enable-migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

So, I need help to configure EF migrations. 
I recently connected to a TFS repository and do a 'Get Latest Version' to a project that uses EF migrations. After I get the code I tried to run Add-Migration but VS said that I need to Enable-Migration first and then when I do I got the following error message:

```
  No context type was found in the assembly
```

Basically, I dont know what to do next. If I got a project from TFS that uses Migration already I can use migrations locally already or I need to enable first? If I need to enable, what I need to do? I tried to point to a project where I have my Web.Config pointing to my database but I don't get any lucky.

Comment: Do you have the project with the context in it selected in the dropdown above the Nuget console?

Comment: Hello Cory! Yes I have. And I try to use the ProjectName and ContextTypeName parameter without any success.

Answer (score 0):

for this you should have to enable maigration on your DataAccess project

```
Enable-Migrations -ProjectName dataAccessProjectName -StartUpProjectName yourWebProject
```

try to run this command on package manage console

Comment: CodeMind, I'm tried this already and get a error too (I cant post the error because I dont have the code with me right now). Changing the subject a little, its seems very strange to me the fact that I need to run enable-migrations when I already have a Configuration.cs file. This is normal?

Comment: Yes.you can Run enable migration at any time.can you just try to delete migration history data from your sql table.some times it will works.because migration hash key might not same as with your database table values.

Answer (score 0):

A few checks you can do -
1. Identify your "data project" in the solution. This is project should have  a reference to "EntityFramework", a DataContext cs file and a "migration" folder.
3. Build your solution,
4. Set your start-up project to the project which typically has config,
5. Switch to "package manager console" and select the data project under the "default project" dropdown.
6. run "add-migration"